# Парсинг src= в html файле

Tags: python-3.x

```
    <div class="ramka"><div class="label_color_yellow">реклама</div>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- MYtricolorTV-top-ssylki-1 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block;height:120px;"`введите сюда код`
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-6002780752776386"
         data-ad-slot="6604387368"
         data-ad-format="link"
         data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script></div>
```

Написал скрипт:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://mytricolortv.com/')
s1 = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")    
m = s1.find_all('script')
print(m)
```

Не получается добраться до src.
Мне нужно вытянуть путь //pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо,Axenow!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать. Чтобы вы потом не ловили исключения, что src нет в soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s1 = BeautifulSoup(open("t.html", "r").read() ,"html.parser")    
m = s1.find_all('script')

sources=s1.findAll('script',{"src":True})
for source in sources:
 print(source['src'])
```

Comment: Спасибо,Axenow!

Comment: @Иван Вы не могли бы тогда пометить ответ как правильный, если она вам помог. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант обратиться к `src` вот так:

```
s1 = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print( s1.select("img")[0].attrs["src"] )
```

Однако, он может вернуть `None`